# a groups based solution to an IMO shortlist problem 2005

Tags: group-theory

(first post sorry if I miss some etiquette)

The problem is as follows:

(IMO SL 2005 C5). There are n markers, each with one side white and
the other side black. In the beginning, these n markers are aligned in a row so that their
white sides are all up. In each step, if possible, we choose a marker whose white side is
up (but not one of the outermost markers), remove it, and reverse the closest marker to
the left of it and also reverse the closest marker to the right of it.
Prove that if n ≡ 1 (mod 3) it’s impossible to reach a state with only two markers
remaining. (In fact the converse is true as well.)

The text I'm reading gives the 'solution':

We have www = bb, bww = wb, wwb = bw, bwb = ww. Interpret these as elements
of D6.

Can anyone explain this solution in more depth?

Comment: Exactly what from the official solution do you think needs further explaining?

Comment: @DerekHolt Doesn't $D_6$ indicate the dihedral group?

Comment: Please use [mathjax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider, in $D_6=\langle x,y|x^6=y^2=e,xy=yx^{-1}\rangle$, the elements $w=x^2$ and $b=y$.

Then in $D_6$, $w^3=b^2(=e)$, $bw^2b^{-1}=(yxy^{-1})^4=(x^{-1})^4=x^2=w$, $b^{-1}w^2b=(y^{-1}xy)^4=x^2=w$, $bwb=(yxy^{-1})^2=(x^{-1})^2=x^4=w^2$.

So, considering a configuration $C$ of markers, we associate with it the element $g(C) \in D_6$ as follows: we run through $C$ left to right, and check each marker one by one, taking a $w$ for the markers on the white side, a $b$ for the others, and we consider the product.

By the previous computations, when $C$ is transferred according to the problem statement, $g(C)$ doesn’t change (talk about far-fetched invariants!!). But, in the initial configuration $C_0$, $g(C_0)=w^n=w$.

So all it remains to do is to check that if $C$ is a configuration with two markers, $g(C)\neq w$. Well, obviously in this case, $g(C) \in \{ww,bw,wb,b^2\}$ and we get the result since $b \neq e$, $b^2=e$ and $w \neq e$.

Comment: thanks so much for a fantastic explanation!